# Using Conditionals(CASE) to retrive a value from another field, if the main requested field is None or empty

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `Image`

```
id  | path      | additional                       | item_id 
1     /url/..     {"sm":"/url2/", "md": "/url3/"}            1
```

`additional` is an jsonb that can be Null, empty {}, or with values

I want to check in jsonb if a key like `sm` exist . If the key exist return the value if not return the `path`.

My starting idea is to use `CASE` but I have issue checking and retrieving the value from array

Comment: What's the datatype of `additional` column?

Comment: Is it an real array or a `jsonb`? An array of what type? Are the funky slashes stored in the database like you show them?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, it is a jsonb in PostgreSQL, (I corrected, appears in code different), the values appear in " ", as key value pairs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `coalesce()`:

```
select id, 
       coalesce(additional ->> 'sm', path) as path
from image;
```

The operator `->>` will return `null` if the key does not exist.

Comment: even if the jsonb is {} or null ?

Comment: @user3541631: yes, even then